# Ubuntu 12.04 as router with 2 nic

Tags: linux, routing, route, networking

I have been trying this setup for weeks and still can not make this to work...

ubuntu 12.04 64 bit with 2 nic

**nic1: eth0:192.168.2.33 -static ip** with internet access (connected to modem)

**nic2: eth1:192.168.1.2 -static ip** connected to LAN.

enabled ip_forward on ubuntu box **net_ip_forward = 1**

on the LAN with ip address 192.168.1.5 specified gateway as 192.168.1.2 and able to ping gateway.But can not ping public address.What am i missing? 
on router box:

```
route -n

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0

192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

**tried**

```
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.2 dev eth0
```

**route -n**   on LAN 192.168.1.5

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         192.168.1.2     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0

192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

192.168.2.0     192.168.1.2     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

iptables default policy is to accept all.

**tracepath 8.8.8.8** from LAN

```
  1:  192.168.1.5                                           0.060ms pmtu 1500

  1:  192.168.1.2                                           3.367ms 

  1:  192.168.1.2                                           3.764ms 

   2:  no reply
```

Is there a way to make this work,other than NAT ing.

Answer (score 1):

192.168.2.1 is not a public address either. What box is that? Does it know how to route traffic back to 192.168.1.5? Does it do NAT for networks other than 192.168.2.0/24?

Comment: 192.168.2.1 is a D-link router connected to a modem.It doesnt know abot 192.168.1.0/24 network.

Comment: There's your problem then.

Comment: Can u please guide me with fixing this.When i used clear os.It worked with out much effort.All i did was specified 192.168.2.1 as external in the graphical mode.But with Ubuntu i am stuck./

Comment: It's not ubuntu that needs configuring, it's the d-link router.

Comment: x2 - your D-Link needs a static route to 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.2.33.  Make sure your D-Link also is set to NAT both subnets.